# No loadedmetadata callback when setting video source

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, blob

I need the video dimensions of a video that is uploaded via an input tag. But when I set the uploaded video as source of a video tag, the loadedmetadata event doesn't get called.

In this method I set the video and the listener:

```
function getVideoDimensionsOf(objUrl){
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
        let video = document.createElement('video');
        //THIS GETS CALLED AS EXPECTED
        video.addEventListener( "loadedmetadata", function () {
            //THIS GETS NEVER CALLED
            let height = this.videoHeight;
            let width = this.videoWidth;
            console.log(height,width)
        }, false );
        video.src = objUrl;
    });
}
```

In this method, I set up the callback for the video upload:

```
function localFileVideoPlayer() {
  var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL
  var uploadSelectedFile = function (event) {
    var file = this.files[0]
    var type = file.type
    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file)
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function() {
        var videofile = this.result;
        //do something here with video data
    };
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    getVideoDimensionsOf(window.URL.createObjectURL(file))//-->>HERE I CALL THE FUNCTION THAT SHOULD SET THE VIDEO SOURCE
  }
  var inputNode = document.getElementById("videofile")
  inputNode.addEventListener('change', uploadSelectedFile, false)
}
```

And this is the html upload field:

```
<div>
    Upload Video:
    <input id="videofile" type="file" accept="video/*"/>
</div>
```

I checked that the getVideoDimensionsOf method gets called, but why is the loadedmetadata listener not getting the callback?

Answer (score 0):

Because nothing forces the browser to preload your video element. 
For all it knows, you will never play this video, so it makes sense it won't preload its content.

You could try to force this preloading by calling its `play()` method.

```js
function getVideoDimensionsOf(objUrl) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    let video = document.createElement('video');
    video.muted = true; // bypass Chrome autoplay policies
    video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function() {
      let height = this.videoHeight;
      let width = this.videoWidth;
      video.pause();
      resolve( { width, height } );
    }, false);
    video.src = objUrl;
    video.play();
  });
}

inp.onchange = e => {
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(inp.files[0]);
  getVideoDimensionsOf(url)
    .then(obj => {
      URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
      console.log(obj);
    });
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="inp" accept="video/*,.mp4">
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
localFileVideoPlayer();

function getVideoDimensionsOf(objUrl) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    let video = document.createElement("video");
    {
      // if you need to append the video to the document
      video.controls = true;
      document.body.appendChild(video);
    }
    //THIS GETS CALLED AS EXPECTED
    video.addEventListener(
      "loadedmetadata",
      function() {
        //THIS GETS NEVER CALLED
        let height = this.videoHeight;
        let width = this.videoWidth;
        console.log(height, width);
      },
      false
    );
    video.src = objUrl;
  });
}
function localFileVideoPlayer() {
  var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
  var uploadSelectedFile = function(event) {
    var file = this.files[0];
    var type = file.type;
    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function() {
      var videofile = this.result;
      //do something here with video data
    };
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    getVideoDimensionsOf(window.URL.createObjectURL(file)); //-->>HERE I CALL THE FUNCTION THAT SHOULD SET THE VIDEO SOURCE
  };
  var inputNode = document.getElementById("videofile");
  inputNode.addEventListener("change", uploadSelectedFile, false);
}
```

```html
<div>
  Upload Video:
  <input id="videofile" type="file" accept="video/*" />
</div>
```

In your code, you need to initialize the input change event using the localFileVideoPlayer method, so I first executed this method. Then if you need to display this video in the document, you need to append a video element to the document, so there is appendChild method in getVideoDimensionsOf